# Ajax call returns only part of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have textarea and button

```
<textarea id="xxx" class="myTextArea" name="Text1" cols="40" rows="15">@ViewData["translation"]</textarea>
<input type="button" id="convert-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Convert to android" />
```

and jquery ajax call which gets value of textarea and sends it to c# ActionResult

```
$("#convert-btn").on("click", function () {
    var translation = $("#xxx").html();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "Translation/ConvertToAndroid",
        data: "translation=" + translation,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger; /*see what happened */
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
            document.write(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What is passed to my ActionResult is only 211 lines string, and text in textarea has 790 lines.

method:

```
var translation = $("#xxx").val();
```

returns error in chrome debugger, only `.html()` is working, but return only part of data from textarea.

Comment: it is an option thats not my choose

Comment: @JaromandaX yes sorry u are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
data: {translation: translation},
```

instead of

```
data: "translation=" + translation,
```

Let jQuery handle the POST parameter stuff for you - my guess is, there's something at line 211 confuses the issue

It could also be a upload size limit in your server

Comment: "data: {translation: translation}," solved problem! Thanks!